# Initialize an array with random indices in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I try to fill an array randomly. I have an rows array:

```
rows = ['1','0','2','1','3'];
```

and columns array:

```
columns = ['0','0','1','2','3'];
```

and a button array:

```
butArray = [];
```

I initialized button array. What I try to

```
printArr[rows[i]][columns[i]] = butArray[i];
```

How exactly should I use loop here?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There are no random indexes

Comment: @Rajesh I try to locate buttons dynamically, I take the rows , columns, button values from user and according to this I print the buttons on the screen.

Comment: @Weedoze Normally I take rows and columns from user.

Comment: @EminÇiftçi Your question is not clear. Please show us what is inside `butArray[]` and what is the final result

Comment: `for(var i=0 ; i<columns.length ; i++){printArr[rows[i]][columns[i]] = butArray[i];}`  ,,.... I don't think you are looking for this answer. Try to explain the output you want..?

Comment: @Weedoze for example `butArray[0] = <input type="button" value="3" class="buttons" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">`

Comment: @EminÇiftçi So if I understand right, you have a finite list of buttons and you accept row, column from user as string and then based on given values, you wish to print values. Still there are lots of dark area in question and would be difficult to answer

Comment: @Hemakumar not exactly `printArr` is a multidimensional array

Comment: Yes I have 10 buttons, and I take rows and columns from user and for example

`rows[0] = 1`
`columns[0] = 2`
`butArray[0] = <input type="button" value="3" class="buttons" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">;`

then `printArr[1][2] = <input type="button" value="3" class="buttons" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">;`

@Rajesh

Comment: @EminÇiftçi What if the number of columns or row is different from the number of buttons ?

Comment: @Weedoze It's not possible I take three of them together

Comment: @EminÇiftçi Can you create a sample JSFiddle with your current code? Its unclear and taking long discussion for clarity. A working example would enable everyone to understand your  problem and possibly give better solutions that us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/1J2VWX0yCIWITQp6Yax8?p=preview
```

// Code goes here

```
function myclick(){
  console.log("cds")
  rows = ['1','0','2','1','3'];
  columns = ['0','0','1','2','3'];
  butArray = ['qwe','qwe','qewe','qew','qwe'];//some values
  var printArr = [];
  for(var i=0 ; i<columns.length ; i++){
    if(printArr[rows[i]] == undefined)
    printArr[rows[i]] = []
    printArr[rows[i]][columns[i]] = butArray[i];

  }
  console.log(printArr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what I exactly looking for.